# Adding multiple slugs in one URL path in Django 3

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to add multiple slugs in one URL path like this:

```
path('<slug:firstslug>/<slug:secondslug>/<slug:thirdslug>/', views.mydetailview, name='detailview')
```

I tried many ways but it didn't work. I want to use normal class based views. All slugs are coming from same model of the same app.

Comment: show your view code that you have tried

Comment: I am having the same issue and most questions regarding this are answered for Django 1 or 2. I am getting `Generic detail view MaxQuantPipelineDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me;

my app > models.py:

```
class Model(models.Model):
constructor         = models.ForeignKey(Constructor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
model_name          = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
slug                = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
model_image         = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', 
                      blank=True)
```

we need to define a function that receives the desired slugs as arguments

```
def get_version(self):
    return reverse('selected_versions', args=[self.constructor.slug, 
    self.slug])
```

my app > views.py:

```
def selected_versions(request, constructor_slug=None, model_slug=None):
constructors = None
models = None
versions = None

if (constructor_slug != None and model_slug != None):
    constructors = get_object_or_404(Constructor, slug=constructor_slug)
    models =get_object_or_404(Model, slug=model_slug)
    versions=Version.objects.filter(constructor=constructorsi, 
              model=models)
else:
    versions=Version.objects.all()
context={
    'version': versions,
}
return render(request, 'versions.html', context)
```

my app > urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<slug:constructor_slug>/<slug:model_slug>/', views.selected_versions, 
      name='selected_versions'),
]
```